# I use multi-thread IO in my net lib demo, but qps doesn't improve

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, networking

I'm writing a net lib demo. And I want to use multi-thread to improve qps. But I found even thread num added, but qps doesn't change. I don't know why. Here is my code: https://github.com/Rhysol/net_lib.

I test it on Centos7 virtual machine, it has 8 cores. Clients sent 1 million requests to the server. I have tested 1,3,7 thread to handle io. They almost cost the same time handle 1 million requests, about 10s. I am not familiar with multi-thread coding, so if there any mistakes in my code?

Comment: How much data is associated with those "... 1 million requests"?  Are you sure the performance isn't IO limited rather than having anything to do with CPU usage?

Comment: 1024 bytes per request, I have used gperftool to analyze the server. 7 IO threads almost cost 60% performance.

Comment: Here is the CPU analyze of 1 IO thread situation.https://github.com/Rhysol/net_lib/blob/master/profiler1.pdf. And I updated the 3 IO threads and 7 IO threads analyzation to the github. Is it possible the bottleneck because of memory malloc?

Comment: And what's the connection medium between client and server?  One million messages of size 1Kbyte amounts to 8Gbit of data.  Allowing for any protocol overhead that would pretty much saturate a Gig ether connection for 10s -- which is what you see.